# Sign of $f(x)=\log(x-1)-\arctan(x-2)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry, logarithms

To find the sign of

$$f(x)=\log(x-1)-\arctan(x-2)$$

I tried searching solutions for

$$\log(x-1)\ge\arctan(x-2)$$

but failed, so I guessed I could use its derivative to find in which intervals the function is monotone, so

$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}+\frac{1}{(x-2)^2+1}=\frac{x^2-5x+6}{(x-1)(x^2-4x+5)}$$

and

$$f'(x)\ge0\iff x\in(1,2]\cup[3,\infty)$$

which means that f(x) is monotone in $(1,2]$, $[2,3]$ and $[3,\infty)$.
The point for that is so I can apply the [Intermediate value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem), since $f(x)$ is continuous $\forall x\in (1,\infty)$, by finding the images of the boundaries of these intervals. If the lower boundary's image is negative and the upper one's image is positive, or viceversa, there is a root. Now, by blind luck:

$$\lim_{x\to1^+}f(x)=\log(0^+)-\arctan(1^+-2)=-\infty$$
$$f(2)=\log(1)-\arctan(0)=0$$

and that gives us both a root and the fact that $\forall x\in (1,2]\;f(x)\le0$.  Great, now

$$f(3)=\log(2)-\frac{\pi}{4}\lt0$$

So no roots here, since $\forall x \in[2,3]\; f(x)\le0$, but at least we know that $\forall x \in(1,3]\; f(x)\le0$. Now here comes the parts I can't solve: given that

$$f(4)=\log(3)-\arctan(2)<0$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=\log(\infty-1)-arctan(\infty-2)=\infty$$

Which means there is a root in $[4,\infty)$, but how do I find it? I can't seam t find a way to actually have a finite value for this root. Many thanks to whoever replies! (A smiley face will do)(Sorry for any errors).

Comment: I believe finding the exact value isn't possible without a calculator.  You could try using the maclaurin series to get a good estimate.

Comment: That could work but given that this problem plus the whole study of $f(x)$ should have been done in no more than 10 maybe 12 minutes, I don't know if I could have managed that.

Comment: How accurate of an answer did they require without a calculator?  If you plug in $x=4$ then do some estimations, it is approximately a root.

Comment: We also have that $f(1+\exp(\frac{\pi}{2}))>0$, for an upper bound on the other root.

Comment: @Ty. they didn't specify how accurate it should have been, actually they didn't say anything about the test. We just had to give as much information about this function as we could.

Comment: @aschepler that's surely better than $\infty$, and I guess it's either that or Maclaurin, seams that it can't be found analitically.